# JAVAFX me borra datos de un ArrayList en vez de retenerlos

Tags: java, array, arraylist, javafx, interfaz-gráfica

Vengo nuevamente a consultar aquí por si alguien tiene experiencia con JAVAFX. Estoy realizando un proyecto que necesito me guarde los usuarios en un ArrayList, estoy usando JAVAFX en el proceso. Por los momentos me guarda bien los usuarios e identifica si son repetidos o no, pero al cerrar la ventana donde se guardan los usuarios y volverla a abrir estos desaparecen. Por ejemplo: Guardo el usuario Juan, cierro esa ventana, vuelvo a entrar y pumm quiero guardar otra vez a Juan y me deja hacerlo cosa que creo no debería ser así jajaja.

He intentado por todos lados que no me haga eso, pero al final siempre lo hace. Espero alguien pueda ayudar con esto si es tan amable.

Dejo el código, aquí:

```
public class Usuarios {

    private String nombre;
    private String username;
    private char password;
    private int edad;

    public Usuarios(String nombre, String username, char password, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(char password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public char getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
}


public class Admin extends Usuarios {

    public Admin(String nombre, String username, char password, int edad) {
        super(nombre, username, password, edad);
    }

    public void agregarUsuarios(Usuarios user, ObservableList<Usuarios> users){
        for(Usuarios u : users){
            if(u.getUsername().equals(user.getUsername())){
                System.out.println("Este usuario ya existe");
                return;
            }
        }

        users.add(user);
        System.out.println("Usuario agregado");
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}

public class AddUsers implements Initializable {

    private ObservableList<Usuarios> usuarios;
    Admin sudo = new Admin("Juan","deafdead",'r',24);

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> usersType = new ComboBox<>();
    ObservableList<String> lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Admin", "Content", "Limit");

    @FXML
    private Button exitAdminUsers, goBack, saveUser;

    @FXML
    private TextField nameField,userField,passField,ageField;

    Main m = new Main();

    public void close() {
        Stage stage = (Stage) exitAdminUsers.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        usersType.setItems(lista);
        usuarios = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public void back() throws IOException {
        m.cambioEscena("AdminMenu.fxml");
    }

    public void save() throws IOException {
        sudo.agregarUsuarios(new Usuarios(nameField.getText(),userField.getText(),'J',Integer.parseInt(ageField.getText())),usuarios);
    }
}

public class Main extends Application {

    private static Stage stg;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        stg = primaryStage;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 520, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void cambioEscena(String fxml) throws IOException{
        Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml));
        stg.getScene().setRoot(pane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que la lista `usuarios` es una variable de instancia de la clase `AddUsers`, por lo que cada vez que se cree una instancia de dicha clase (esto ocurre cada vez que inicias la vista asociada) se creará una nueva instancia de la lista.

Una posible solución es que declares el atributo como `static` y de este modo ya no será una variable de instancia sino de clase, por lo que la misma misma instancia será compartida por todas las instancias de la clase `AddUsers`. Claro, que para que esto funcione bien solo debes inicializar la lista `usuarios` una vez, sino vas a seguir teniendo el mismo comportamiento.

```
public class AddUsers implements Initializable {

    private ObservableList<Usuarios> usuarios;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        // ...
        
        // Solo inicializar la variable si no se a hecho anteriormente
        if (usuarios == null) {
            usuarios = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Otras soluciones serían almacenar los datos de los usuarios en un archivo, base de datos, etc.